# Read JSON array from file for pymongo

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to read a JSON array from a file and want to pass it to pymongo to write multiple documents into a collection.

I have already tried to read the file as normal text with file.read() but the pymongo.insert_many() expect a list and not a string, so I though I have to parse it as JSON, but it drops an error.

My JSON file looks like this just more data

```
[

    {
        "name": "Aayla Secura",
        "nickname": [],
        "light": [],
        "dark": [],
        "cantina": ["5-B"],
        "shops": ["guild shop"],
        "faction": ["Light Side", "Support", "Galactic Republic", "Jedi"],
        "chImage": "https://swgoh.gg/static/img/assets/tex.charui_aaylasecura.png"
    },

    {
        "name": "Admiral Ackbar",
        "nickname": ["AA"],
        "light": [],
        "dark": [],
        "cantina": [],
        "shops": ["arena", "fleet", "guild events"],
        "faction": ["Light Side", "Support", "Fleet Commander", "Rebel"],
        "chImage": "https://swgoh.gg/static/img/assets/tex.charui_ackbaradmiral.png"
    },

    {
        "name": "Ahsoka Tano",
        "nickname": [],
        "light": [],
        "dark": ["4-C"],
        "cantina": [],
        "shops": ["cantina", "fleet"],
        "faction": ["Light Side", "Attacker", "Galactic Republic", "Jedi"],
        "chImage": "https://swgoh.gg/static/img/assets/tex.charui_ahsoka.png"
    }
]
```

And this is what I tried:

```py
import json


with open('characters.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
```

I have tried both the json.load() , and json.loads() , but all drops error.
I have also tried to use ujson insted of json, but also drops error.

Any idea how can I pass the file content to pymongo as a python list???

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your json is not a valid json, if you try to parse this:

```
[

    {
        "name": "Aayla Secura",
        "nickname": [],
        "light": [],
        "dark": [],
        "cantina": ["5-B"],
        "shops": ["guild shop"],
        "faction": ["Light Side", "Support", "Galactic Republic", "Jedi"],
        "chImage": "https://swgoh.gg/static/img/assets/tex.charui_aaylasecura.png"
    },

    {
        "name": "Admiral Ackbar",
        "nickname": ["AA"],
        "light": [],
        "dark": [],
        "cantina": [],
        "shops": ["arena", "fleet", "guild events"],
        "faction": ["Light Side", "Support", "Fleet Commander", "Rebel"],
        "chImage": "https://swgoh.gg/static/img/assets/tex.charui_ackbaradmiral.png"
    },

    {
        "name": "Ahsoka Tano",
        "nickname": [],
        "light": [],
        "dark": ["4-C"],
        "cantina": [],
        "shops": ["cantina", "fleet"],
        "faction": ["Light Side", "Attacker", "Galactic Republic", "Jedi"],
        "chImage": "https://swgoh.gg/static/img/assets/tex.charui_ahsoka.png"
    }
]
```

With this code:

```
import json


with open('characters.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.loads(file.read())
```

It will work.

Comment: I have tried it already but drop error:
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 24 column 15 (char 698)

Comment: then your json is not a valid json, try using this tool to analyze it: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: The "name": "chef chirpa", field on line 25 is breaking the json parse

Comment: Yes, just recognized it now, but the original file does not have this issue, I have done it whet put example here. without that part still cannot parse :(

Comment: I found an other error in the json file , so it is OK now. Your suggestion is OK
THX!

Comment: Great, I am glad I helped you out :D